# Understanding blender for 3d modeling

Tags: 3d-printing

I was trying do model simple box with opened top for 3d print. I added plane, extrude the edges in Z axis and applied solidify modifier.
The model looks fine, however the Cura cant slice it properly (it slices only the bottom). I really dont understand, what I'm doing wrong, because as soon, as I extrude something, it immediately gets unsliceable. Could somebody provide me a hint, on what to focus?
File is here:
[Cube](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1neXsM1GyuhsQGON2ZrXP3H6dxQJMFfZX/view?usp=sharing)
[image]

[image]

Update: I do use the 3d print addon, you can see it on the screenshot from blender.

Comment: Have you checked if the mesh is manifold ? Hard to say since you have X ray enabled

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your walls are too thin. The 3D printer's nozzle is probably wider than the 3D wall, and the slicer is rejecting that part of the model. I'm pretty sure if you thicken the walls, it will work :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the 3D printing add on? This will let you prepare your model ready for 3D printing. YouTube the blender 3D printing add on, there are lots of videos.

Also cura has a blender plug-in which is brilliant because you don’t have to export an stl file then reimport it into blender, you can just open the blender file directly in cura. Just make sure you have you dimensions set up correctly so the model import at the correct size.